# Modification of Search.php to show contact form if the search does not return value

Tags: wordpress

I have these templates from Flatsome and Storefront, and I would like to improve them by adding functionality. I have followed several manuals to modify the search.php file, but with none I have managed to load a contact form. I do not know if it is necessary to modify any other component.

If you need any more data, I copy the code of each file.